# What is going on in the mysterious western half of Bangkok?

Tags: bangkok

Chao Phraya River halves Bangkok into eastern and western halves. Almost all travel guides are talking about attractions and accommodations that are in the east part. This makes me think about what is going on on the west side. The western part of Bangkok seems to me like a mysterious forbidden city.

Enlighten me, what is going on there and are any things worth a visit to the western part? How different is it from the east half?

Comment: Sounds like Paris and London south of their rivers, Amsterdam Noord (north of the water behind the central station) and more cities which basically started on one side of a main waterway. The other half was just countryside before the recent times or a minor part of the city which did not attract that much special things.

Comment: @Willeke: Paris has a lot of nice attractions on both sides of the Seine River (maybe more on the North side but it is mostly because the Seine does not divide the city in equal parts). Actually, the historical city (Lutecia) was on an island (Ile de la Cite, where Notre-Dame cathedral is located) on the river and the city expanded early in both directions.

Comment: @Willeke "Sounds like Paris", hum, no?

Comment: @Willeke - I'm from south london. There really isn't anything worth seeing this side of the river unless you want to see elephant and castle

Comment: @Willeke The Eiffel Tower is south of the Seine

Comment: Maybe Paris is not as empty of sights south of the river but Bangkok is also not empty of sights West of the river.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The western half of Bangkok is called **[Thonburi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thonburi)**, and there's nothing particularly mysterious about why it's quieter.  Thonburi was in fact the seat of the Thai kingdom until 1782, when king Rama I decreed that it should be moved to the other side of the Chao Phraya River in order to better defend against the Burmese threatening from the west side.  And that's pretty much it: the then-new Royal Palace was built in the east and the modern city grew up around it, eventually including what we think of as the core of modern Bangkok, namely the business and shopping districts of Silom and Sukhumvit.  Only in the late 2000s did the Skytrain & MRT train systems even cross the river to Thonburi.

All that said, Thonburi has definitely been undergoing a renaissance lately, centered around the massive [Iconsiam](https://www.iconsiam.com/th) mall with its associated hotel and apartment developments and the new Gold Line train connecting them to the Skytrain.  And [Wat Arun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wat_Arun) (Temple of Dawn), arguably Bangkok's if not Thailand's most famous temple, has been on the Thonburi side of the river since the 1600s.  Check out [Thonburi on Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bangkok/Thonburi) for more things to see and do, there's plenty!

Finally, funnily enough, the English name "Bangkok" likely comes from the village of Bang Makok on the Thonburi side, and predates the relocation of the capital.  The Thais call Bangkok **Krung Thep** instead.

Comment: So what happened to the old Royal Palace in Thonburi (assuming there was one)

Comment: @lalala It's still there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thonburi_Palace

Comment: Thanks. Needs a bit of preparation to visit.

Comment: @lalala old palace becomes Navy HQ. A few famous temple around it. other than that nothing much for the tourists.

Comment: Could we please cease using Wikipedia ? It's so unreliable it's not even funny.

Comment: @chx What makes you think it's any more unreliable than Travel.SE?  Or are you saying that in this particular case it's wrong about the western half of Bangkok being called Thonburi?

Comment: We do not have organized trolling going on unlike with Wikipedia. We are a smaller target.

Comment: @chx Do you have any grounds to claim that there is more trolling on the Wikipedia pages for particular landmarks than there is here on travel.SE? Not all Wikipedia pages are equal in that respect, do you know anything about tourist-focused pages in particular?